# Content in Nav-bar not aligning properly

Tags: html, css, position

I am trying to make a navigation bar using icons from css.gg, and when I try to make the content go from left to right, it doesn't align properly. It just smoshes together, or one icon goes under below another.

Here is an image for reference:
[image: REFERENCE IMAGE]

I have tried using both `display: inline;` and `float: left;`
which worked better, but didn't make everything work, as the third icon would end up under the other 2 icons.

Here is my code. The part grouped in `=====`... is where the problem probably lies.

```css
@import url('https://css.gg/games.css');
@import url('https://css.gg/comment.css');
@import url('https://css.gg/home-alt.css');

/*==============================================================================================*/

/* Nav Bar */

nav {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1%;
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-right: 45%;
}


/* ICONS */

.gg-home-alt {
  /* This value will multiple the actual size  */
  --ggs: 1.5;
}

.gg-comment {
  /* This value will multiple the actual size  */
  --ggs: 1.5;
}

.gg-games {
  /* This value will multiple the actual size  */
  --ggs: 1.5;
}


/* END OF ICONS */

li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}


/* Anchor/hyperlink content */

a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/*================================================================================================*/

#mainSite {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
}


/* Text based/body content */

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #67c3f9;
  /*
    background-image: url("https://68.media.tumblr.com/c5552d48c39cb834d0f5c249869d4737/tumblr_oiln82yPI91w0f40yo1_500.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 75%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
  */
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 40%;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}


/* Input content */

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

form input {
  background: none;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  padding: 0px 17px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Games Page CSS */

#gTitle {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

.gamesTable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="g.html" class="navLinks"><i class="gg-games"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://discord.gg/jatF5KbCrT" class="navLinks"><i class="gg-comment"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/index.html" class="navLinks"><i class="gg-home-alt"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<body>
  <!-- This is the main content of the website -->
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Plunge Proxy</h1>
  </div>
  <form>
    <input id="search" placeholder="Enjoy the Internet!" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you're looking for or share a working example of the error you are getting?  When I put your code from the question into [codepen](https://codepen.io/sean-conkie/pen/KKBMwzz) it looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

/* ICONS */
.gg-home-alt {
  /* This value will multiple the actual size  */
  --ggs: 1.5;

}

.gg-comment {
  /* This value will multiple the actual size  */
  --ggs: 1.5;

}

.gg-games {
  /* This value will multiple the actual size  */
  --ggs: 1.5;

}

/* END OF ICONS */

ul {
  width: inherit;
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* Anchor/hyperlink content */
a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 15px;
}

================================================================================================#mainSite {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
}

/* Text based/body content */
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #67c3f9;
  /*
    background-image: url("https://68.media.tumblr.com/c5552d48c39cb834d0f5c249869d4737/tumblr_oiln82yPI91w0f40yo1_500.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 75%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
  */
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 40%;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: white;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}


/* Input content */
form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

form input {
  background: none;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  padding: 0px 17px;
  height: 48px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  outline: none;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Games Page CSS */

#gTitle {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

.gamesTable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://css.gg/home-alt.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://css.gg/comment.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://css.gg/games.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="g.html" class="navLinks"><i class="gg-games"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="https://discord.gg/jatF5KbCrT" class="navLinks"><i class="gg-comment"></i></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/index.html" class="navLinks"><i class="gg-home-alt"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<body>
  <!-- This is the main content of the website -->
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Plunge Proxy</h1>
  </div>
  <form>
    <input id="search" placeholder="Enjoy the Internet!" />
  </form>
```